# Numerically approximating eigenstates and energies of a particle subject to some potential. Question about dirac orthonormality and infinite terms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, hamiltonian, matrix-elements

### Context

I am attempting to approximate the eigenstates and energies of a particle over an interval $[-a,a]$ subject to some potential.

The goal is then to approximate the wavefunction $\Psi$ with respect to an arbitrary basis that spans the interval: $\psi_i(x)=\Delta^{-1/2}\mathcal{H}(x-x_i)\mathcal{H}(x_{i+1}-x)$, where $x_{i+1}=x_i+\Delta$ and $\mathcal{H}$ is the Heaviside function. We define $\Delta$ to be the length of the interval divided by the number of subdivisions (subintervals) $\Delta=2a/N$.
$$
\Psi(x)\approx\sum_{i=0}^N c_i \left|\psi_i\right>
$$

### The equation

We form the matrix equation $H_{ji}c_i = E\delta_{ji} c_i$ by taking the inner product with  the Schrödinger equation, where $H_{ji}=\left<\psi_j\right|\hat{H}\left|\psi_i\right>$. To actually calculate each $H_{ji}$ we must compute the sum of the quantities $T_{ji}$ and $V_{ji}$. Each $V_{ji}$ easy since this is just the average of $V$ over the interval when $i=j$, but I believe this is zero when $i\ne j$ since the basis is orthonormal: $\left<\psi_j\right|\hat{V}\left|\psi_i\right>=\bar{V}\left<\psi_j\big|\psi_i\right>=\bar{V}\delta_{ji}$.

### The Problem

However, I run into a difficulty for the kinetic integral:
$
\left<\psi_j\right|\hat{T}\left|\psi_i\right>
=\int \psi_j\hat{T}\psi_i dx
$.
We may apply the hermitian properties of $\hat{p}$ with the relation $\hat{T}=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}$.
$$
\left<\psi_j\right|\hat{T}\left|\psi_i\right>
=\frac{1}{2m}\int (\hat{p}^*\psi_j) (\hat{p}\psi_i) dx
=\frac{1}{2m}\int (\hat{p}\psi_j) (\hat{p}\psi_i) dx
$$
So computing the partial derivative gives:
$$
%\begin{matrix}
\hat{p}\psi_i
=-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial_x}\psi_i = -\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{\Delta}} \frac{\partial }{\partial_x}\mathcal{H}(x-x_i)\mathcal{H}(x_{i+1}-x)
$$
$$
=-\frac{i\hbar}{\sqrt{\Delta}} \left[
   \mathcal{H}(x_{i+1}-x)\frac{\partial }{\partial_x}\mathcal{H}(x-x_i)
   +
   \mathcal{H}(x-x_i)\frac{\partial }{\partial_x}\mathcal{H}(x_{i+1}-x) \right]
%\end{matrix}
$$
Where the partial derivative of the heaviside step function is a dirac delta function:
$$
\hat{p}\psi_i
=-\frac{i\hbar}{\sqrt{\Delta}}
\left[
\mathcal{H}(x_{i+1}-x)\delta(x-x_i)
-\mathcal{H}(x-x_i)\delta(x_{i+1}-x)
\right]
$$
So then the product in the integral may be written as:
$$
(\hat{p}\psi_j) (\hat{p}\psi_i)
= -\frac{\hbar^2}{\Delta}
\left[
\mathcal{H}(x_{j+1}-x)\delta(x-x_j)
-\mathcal{H}(x-x_j)\delta(x_{j+1}-x)
\right]
\left[
\mathcal{H}(x_{i+1}-x)\delta(x-x_i)
-\mathcal{H}(x-x_i)\delta(x_{i+1}-x)
\right]
$$
Which expands to a sum of products of the form
$
\mathcal{H}(x_{j+1}-x)\delta(x-x_j)\mathcal{H}(x_{i+1}-x)\delta(x-x_i)
$,
and as far as I can tell, each of the four terms integrates to something like
$
\mathcal{H}(x_{j+1}-x_i)\delta(x_i-x_j)\mathcal{H}(x_{i+1}-x_i)
$.
Since $x_{i+1}>x_i$, this reduces to
$
\mathcal{H}(x_{j+1}-x_i)\delta(x_i-x_j)
$.
When $i=j$, this reduces to $1\cdot\infty$.

### The question

Since this is related to dirac orthonormality, then how do I produce a matrix with non-infinite entries?

### My hunch

I suppose that any meaningful answer will arrive at the conclusion that the result is zero, or perhaps just zero *almost* everywhere.

Comment: $V(x)=\alpha|x|$ is not a harmonic oscillator potential, or an approximation of one. A harmonic oscillator potential is quadratic.

Comment: … and has continuous derivatives everywhere.

Comment: @Ghoster and ZeroTheHero, I specifically said ***approximation*** of the simple harmonic oscillator. Over a larger domain, the aproximation will require multiple linear segments to more accurately capture the larger parabolic potential. For complete accuracy the parabolic potential may be use. Ultimately, this is related to the WKB approximation.

This is also irrelevant. And I apologize for including so much information as to confuse you. I will remove the offending text so as to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be fairly trivial. $\delta(x_i-x_j)$ does in fact reduce to a Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$. The exact reason is beyond me.